# I get an error message "Could not execute JDBC batch update" when using hibernate "Many to Many"

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I configured a "question-tag" Many-to-Many relationship.in Hibernate
When I test it with a small program, it has the follwing error:
(My Hibernate version is 3.1)

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.hibernate.cfg.Environment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Hibernate: insert into javaqa2.qa_tag (creator_id, name, description, create_date, used_cnt) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into javaqa2.qa_tag (creator_id, name, description, create_date, used_cnt) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into javaqa2.qa_question (creator_id, subject, content, creator_ip, question_tags, upvote_cnt, downvote_cnt, visit_cnt, answer_cnt, comment_cnt, istopmost, islocked, isanonym, create_date) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into qa_question_tags (question_id, tag_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into qa_question_tags (question_id, tag_id) values (?, ?)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.handledNonSpecificException(SQLStateConverter.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:91)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:202)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:297)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:985)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:333)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:106)
    at test.Test1.main(Test1.java:49)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: No database selected
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchSerially(PreparedStatement.java:1669)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatch(PreparedStatement.java:1085)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:58)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:195)
    ... 8 more
```

This is my Test Program:
public class Test1 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Configuration cfg=new Configuration().configure();
    SessionFactory sf=cfg.buildSessionFactory();
    Session session = sf.openSession();
    Transaction trans = session.beginTransaction();

    Student student = (Student)session.load(Student.class, Integer.valueOf(45));
    Question question=new Question(student, "test8881","test8882",
            "192.168,88.88","Java,dotNet,Struts2",  0,0,0,0,0,
            Boolean.FALSE, Boolean.FALSE, Boolean.FALSE,
            new Date());
    Tag tag1=new Tag(student,"test tag1","test tag1",new Date(),0);
    Tag tag2=new Tag(student,"test tag2","test tag2",new Date(),0);

    session.save(tag1);
    session.save(tag2);

    Set<Tag> tagList =new HashSet<Tag>();
    tagList.add(tag1);
    tagList.add(tag2);

    question.setTags(tagList); // when add this line... error occurs

    session.save(question);
    trans.commit();
}
```

**This program runs well when the method setTags(tagList)  is not called for question,
however, when I add this method call, the error occurs. (see the comment in the program).**

This is the portion of Question.hbm.xml defined Many-to-Many properties.

```
    <set name="tags" table="qa_question_tags" lazy="true" cascade="all">
        <key column="question_id"/>
        <many-to-many class="model.Tag" column="tag_id"/>
    </set>
```

I have set the following property in my hibernate.cfg.xml to ensure the table will be updated automatically.

```
<property name="hbm2ddl.auto"> update </property>
```

I was confused with the error message, and please tell me where is the wrong?

Comment: The error seems to be because of some mysql jdbc configuration but since it works in one scenario, can you update the post with the hibernate queries that are executed when question.setTags(tagList) is NOT called?

Comment: Hibernate: insert into javaqa2.qa_question (creator_id, subject, content, creator_ip, question_tags, upvote_cnt, downvote_cnt, visit_cnt, answer_cnt, comment_cnt, istopmost, islocked, isanonym, create_date) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into javaqa2.qa_tag (creator_id, name, description, create_date, used_cnt) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into javaqa2.qa_tag (creator_id, name, description, create_date, used_cnt) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into qa_question_tags (question_id, tag_id) values (?, ?)

Comment: @Andy Dufresne, I firtly suspected jdbc configuration too. However, the query when setTag(tagList) is not called is above and seems normal. Sorry, the comment is not formatted well.

Comment: Do you know why the insert on the qa_question table is executed before the insert queries on qa_tag. The above code indicates that tags are saved first and then question.

Comment: Sorry, I run my program again, and the insert on qa_tag table is before qa_question. Perhaps I changed the save() order. Thus I have edited my question.

Comment: However, @Andy Defresne, thanks for your carefulness and patience, I have found the point in Hibernate queries. "insert into qa_question_tags(...)" is absent of the catalog "javaqa2" compared with "insert into javaqa2.qa_question(...)".

Answer (score 0):

I have found the point in my hibernate queries, thanks for the patience and carefulness of @Andy Defresne .

In the log below:

```
Hibernate: insert into javaqa2.qa_tag (creator_id, name, description, create_date, used_cnt) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into javaqa2.qa_tag (creator_id, name, description, create_date, used_cnt) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into javaqa2.qa_question (creator_id, subject, content, creator_ip, question_tags, upvote_cnt, downvote_cnt, visit_cnt, answer_cnt, comment_cnt, istopmost, islocked, isanonym, create_date) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into qa_question_tags (question_id, tag_id) values (?, ?)
Hibernate: insert into qa_question_tags (question_id, tag_id) values (?, ?)
```

The last two lines of "insert into qa_question_tags" are absent of "javaqa." catalog.

So I add the following property **catalog="javaqa2"** in the Question.hbm.xml :

```
<set name="tags" table="qa_question_tags" lazy="true" cascade="all" catalog="javaqa2">
        <key column="question_id"/>
        <many-to-many class="model.Tag" column="tag_id"/>
</set>
```

Then the problem is solved and the error disappears.

To be complete , I post my Question.hbm.xml, and found catalog properties set in the `<class>` tag is not enough, it must be set in the   `<set>`  tag again:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="model.Question" table="qa_question" catalog="javaqa2">
        ...
       <set name="tags" table="qa_question_tags" lazy="true" cascade="all" catalog="javaqa2">
        <key column="question_id"/>
        <many-to-many class="model.Tag" column="tag_id"/>
       </set> 
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```